# How to parse WSDL (Error: Failed to parse wsdl: Unknown element: import)

Tags: wsdl2apex

I have wsdl file i want to parse wsdl into APEX but when i try to do this i get following error::"Error: Failed to parse wsdl: Unknown element: import"

MY WSDL/XML file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<wsdl:definitions name="ExternalServiceFacade" targetNamespace="http://www.materialise.be/eRP" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="http://www.materialise.be/eRP" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:i0="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata">
  <wsdl:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/" location="https://sv7767.si-servers.com/Streamics-test/External.svc?wsdl=wsdl0" /> 
- <wsdl:types>
- <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.materialise.be/eRP/Imports">
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="https://sv7767.si-servers.com/Streamics-test/External.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://www.materialise.be/eRP" /> 
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="https://sv7767.si-servers.com/Streamics-test/External.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" /> 
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="https://sv7767.si-servers.com/Streamics-test/External.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/eRP.ExternalService.Model" /> 
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="https://sv7767.si-servers.com/Streamics-test/External.svc?xsd=xsd3" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/eRP.ExternalService.Model.Base" /> 
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="https://sv7767.si-servers.com/Streamics-test/External.svc?xsd=xsd4" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" /> 
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="https://sv7767.si-servers.com/Streamics-test/External.svc?xsd=xsd5" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Materialise.eRP.Entities" /> 
  </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
- <wsdl:message name="IExternalService_CreateCustomer_InputMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:CreateCustomer" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:message name="IExternalService_CreateCustomer_OutputMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:CreateCustomerResponse" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:message name="IExternalService_CreateCustomerWithContactPersons_InputMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:CreateCustomerWithContactPersons" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:message name="IExternalService_CreateCustomerWithContactPersons_OutputMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:CreateCustomerWithContactPersonsResponse" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:message name="IExternalService_UpdateCustomer_InputMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:UpdateCustomer" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:message name="IExternalService_UpdateCustomer_OutputMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:UpdateCustomerResponse" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:message name="IExternalService_GetCustomersCount_InputMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetCustomersCount" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:message name="IExternalService_GetCustomersCount_OutputMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetCustomersCountResponse" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:message name="IExternalService_GetAllCustomers_InputMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetAllCustomers" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:message name="IExternalService_GetAllCustomers_OutputMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetAllCustomersResponse" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:portType name="IExternalService">
- <wsdl:operation name="CreateCustomer">
  <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://www.materialise.be/eRP/ICustomerService/CreateCustomer" message="tns:IExternalService_CreateCustomer_InputMessage" /> 
  <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://www.materialise.be/eRP/ICustomerService/CreateCustomerResponse" message="tns:IExternalService_CreateCustomer_OutputMessage" /> 
  </wsdl:operation>
- <wsdl:operation name="CreateCustomerWithContactPersons">
  <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://www.materialise.be/eRP/ICustomerService/CreateCustomerWithContactPersons" message="tns:IExternalService_CreateCustomerWithContactPersons_InputMessage" /> 
  <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://www.materialise.be/eRP/ICustomerService/CreateCustomerWithContactPersonsResponse" message="tns:IExternalService_CreateCustomerWithContactPersons_OutputMessage" /> 
  </wsdl:operation>
- <wsdl:operation name="UpdateCustomer">
  <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://www.materialise.be/eRP/ICustomerService/UpdateCustomer" message="tns:IExternalService_UpdateCustomer_InputMessage" /> 
  <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://www.materialise.be/eRP/ICustomerService/UpdateCustomerResponse" message="tns:IExternalService_UpdateCustomer_OutputMessage" /> 
  </wsdl:operation>
- <wsdl:operation name="GetCustomersCount">
  <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://www.materialise.be/eRP/ICustomerService/GetCustomersCount" message="tns:IExternalService_GetCustomersCount_InputMessage" /> 
  <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://www.materialise.be/eRP/ICustomerService/GetCustomersCountResponse" message="tns:IExternalService_GetCustomersCount_OutputMessage" /> 
  </wsdl:operation>
- <wsdl:operation name="GetAllCustomers">
  <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://www.materialise.be/eRP/ICustomerService/GetAllCustomers" message="tns:IExternalService_GetAllCustomers_InputMessage" /> 
  <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://www.materialise.be/eRP/ICustomerService/GetAllCustomersResponse" message="tns:IExternalService_GetAllCustomers_OutputMessage" /> 
  </wsdl:operation>
- <wsdl:service name="ExternalServiceFacade">
- <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IExternalService" binding="i0:BasicHttpBinding_IExternalService">
  <soap:address location="https://sv7767.si-servers.com/Streamics-test/External.svc" /> 
  </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
  </wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: I think apex is not able to import the types.  Can you try copy paste the types from all import tags in this XML and try again?

Answer (score 2):

The "Generate from WSDL" (aka wsdl2apex) tooling has a number of limitations in the WSDL and XSD Schema that it can handle. See the "Supported WSDL Features" section of [SOAP Services: Defining a Class from a WSDL Document](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm). Sometimes it is possible to edit the WSDL to work around those limitations.

In this case you need to get the XML Schema files from the `schemaLocation` listed early in the WSDL and replace the `xsd:import`s with the XML Schema file content itself. You can use tools such as [online WSDL validators](https://www.wsdl-analyzer.com/) to check your editing. Then try "Generate from WSDL" again and address any further problems.

Answer (score 2):

I've been working on a tool that extends the Apex support for WSDLs without the need to manually manipulate the WSDL before hand. One of the features is explict support for `wsdl:import` elements.

You can get it for Windows via http://www.fuseit.com/Solutions/SFDC-Explorer/Help-WSDL-Parser.aspx. (Disclaimer: I work for the company that makes this tool. It is free to download and use.)

It will need to executed on a machine where https://sv7767.si-servers.com can be resolved.

Note also, your WSDL as listed in the question is missing the closing `</wsdl:portType>` tag. The tool won't be able to compensate for invalid XML.